# Controller não enxerga ng-model do Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, ionic

O controller CriarCtrl não está enxergando o ng-model do input do meu formulário.
Consigo passar valores do controller para a view mas não estou conseguindo o inverso.
Onde estou errando?

Controller:

```
    .controller('CriarCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.criarDemanda = function () {
        console.log($scope.name);
    }
})
```

View:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="name" name="nome" required />
<button class="button button-assertive button-block activated" ng-click="criarDemanda()">Enviar</button>
```

Comment: Tenta fazer isso: `ng-click="criarDemanda(name)"` e no seu controller: `$scope.criarDemanda = function (name)`  e depois `console.log(name)`

Comment: Entendi mas tenho 20 inputs e quero mandar todos os ng-models para o controller no clique do botão. Seria correto enviar um array com todos?

Comment: O ideal é ter um objeto com todas as propriedades. Então da maneira como o @Techies falou você passaria apenas o objeto "pessoa".

Answer (score 3):

Tente enviar um objeto.

```
ng-click="demanda.name"
```

Se tiver mais atributos que entrem nessa demanda é só ir seguindo esse padrão, exemplo:

```
ng-click="demanda.quantidade"
```

Depois é só passar a demanda para o método chamado no `ng-click`:

```
 ng-click="criarDemanda(demanda)
```

Tentei achar uma forma de responder essa sua dúvida e se eu explicar da maneira que eu "entendo" é capaz de você se confundir.

De uma olhadinha aqui: http://tableless.com.br/criando-uma-aplicacao-simples-com-angularjs/

E se for bom de inglês de uma olhada na documentação do Angular.

Comment: Resolveu. Era exatamente isso. Muito obrigado. Mas ficou a dúvida: Porque o controller não enxerga o ng-model do input? Alguem sabe explicar?

Comment: De uma olhadinha aqui: https://jsfiddle.net/joshdmiller/HB7LU/ veja que um exemplo semelhante ao seu código também funciona. O Controller enxerga sua view e vice versa

Answer (score 1):

A diretiva ngModel é responsável por fazer a ligação entre um input, select, textarea, entre outro controles para uma propriedade no scope, sem a necessidade de passar tais informações como argumentos para qualquer método.

Para maiores informações veja https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel

Segue exemplo funcionando de maneira correta.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div id="entityScope" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="CriarCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="name" name="nome" required />
    <button ng-click="criarDemanda()">Enviar</button>
</div>    
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('CriarCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.criarDemanda = function () {
        console.log($scope.name);
    }
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```